# How to check if two LocalTimes are in the same day?

Tags: java, localtime, time-format

From my UI I'm passing two LocalTime values; from time and to time. Both times are

> LocalTime HH:mm

formatted.
Now I need to check whether these times are in the same day.
For an example if someone passes fromTime - 18:00 and toTime - 10:00, I need throw an exception.
I need to check whether both times are in same day.

I tried with DateUtils.isSameDay() but it accepts dates. In my case I have only time.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: "if someone passes fromTime - 18:00 and toTime - 10:00, I need throw an exception" <- so in other words you want to check if one time is after the other and not before? There are methods just for that (`isAfter` and `isBefore`). Times don't have any day so "check if both times in the same day" makes no sense.

Comment: `if (fromTime.isBefore(toTime))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LocalTime` [does not store or represent a date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) or time-zone. So you can't check if two instances are on the same date.

Just see if the "from" time [is before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore-java.time.LocalTime-) the "to" time.

If you need to store date as well, use [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).